# Android and popping from Activity C to Activity A or B

Tags: android, android-activity

I have three activities in my activity stack, A (main) -> B -> C.

A starts B starts C.

My C is a dialog box with one button that will take me to A and one button that will take me to B. The Activity B must therefore have history, so if C calls `finish()` I will always end up in B.

Given this, how do I (efficiently) set this up? i.e. how do I (efficiently) go from C to A?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that you want to finish() B if the user selects the A button on C. Have B start C for a result (`startActivityForResult()`) and have C send back to B the result. If the result is "go to A", then B can just finish().

Answer (score 2):

One way is to set up the onActivityResult method in activity B.

Based on the button clicked, return from activity C with different return codes, which you can access in the onActivityResult method of activity B. Based on the return code, you can either stay on the activity B, or close the activity which will take you to activity A.

Comment: Exactly. I took @Ted's answer and put a switch condition in an if block in onActivityResult. Then use the `setResult(int)` in activity C to communicate with B. This is all I needed.